# Grid with DataContext of DataView won't display data after DataTable.Clear and DataAdapter.Fill

Tags: wpf, dataview, dataadapter

I'll apologize in advance for a long post.  I have two DataTables (Cases and Jobs), each with a DataView that I bind my GUI to (the Cases dataview is the DataContext for a Grid, while the Jobs dataview is the ItemsSource of a ListView and the DataContext of a TabControl).  The first time I fill the tables with DataAdapter.Fill, the data shows properly for cases and jobs.  The second time I load data, I call DataTable.Clear and then DataAdapter.Fill, but only the jobs data shows in the GUI.  The case data is nowhere to be seen, even though stepping through I can tell there's a row in the DataTable with the correct data.  That is, the DataTable.Clear and DataAdapter.Fill work properly; the Grid control in my GUI just doesn't show the data.  I've copied the XAML for the Grid control below.  Can anyone help me?!  Thanks.

UPDATE: If I have more than one row in the table the second time around, data shows up in the text boxes properly!  What the hell is going on?

```
<Grid Height="165" Width="390" DataContext="{Binding caseTableView}" >

            <Grid.Resources>
                <local:CaseStatusItemsSource x:Key="StatusesSource" />
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>            
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!--Case Details-->
            <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >Case Number:</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" IsReadOnly="{Binding isROCaseNumber}" LostFocus="caseNumber_LostFocus" >
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="/CASENUMBER" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:CaseNumberValidationRule />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>

            <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" >Date Received:</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=/DATERECEIVED, StringFormat=d}" IsReadOnly="{Binding isRODateReceived}" />

            <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" >Status:</Label>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Width="140" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="9" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding statuses, Source={StaticResource StatusesSource}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=/STATUS, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="{Binding isROCaseStatus}" >
            </ComboBox>

            <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" >Date Ord. Received:</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=/DATEORDRECEIVED, StringFormat=d}" IsReadOnly="{Binding isRODateOrdReceived}" />

            <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" >Date Posted:</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=/DATEPOSTED, StringFormat=d}" IsReadOnly="{Binding isRODatePosted}" />

        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be a bug in Microsoft's code somewhere, because I fixed it with the code shown below.

```
            ICollectionView _cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_appModel.casesTable);
            _cv.MoveCurrentToNext();
```

I only needed to do this for the case table, not the jobs table, which is why I expect there's a bug somewhere.  The jobs table always worked whether there was one or more than one row in the table.